# gcc no such file or directory error

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to compile a C program and am required to use these flags. I was hoping you could tell me why I am getting these errors.

Command:

```
gcc -ansi –Wall –pedantic stack.c
```

Output:

> gcc: –Wall: No such file or directory
>
> gcc: –pedantic: No such file or directory

Comment: This is not a hyphen/minus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's

```
gcc -ansi -Wall -pedantic
```

You're using one of those dashes: [Dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) (specifically, you are using en-dash U+2013). You need to use minus sign `-` instead